# Convert array into object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a own Array class. Like this:

```
myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords');  // return Array(...)
```

At the same time, How can I do like this?

```
myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords');                // return Array(...)
myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords')->as_object();   // return Object{...}
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject), it behaves the same as any other array and you can extend it (or your class?).

In your case I'd return something like MyArrayObject (your class extending ArrayObject with method as_object() etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can't because an array doesn't have an as_object method. I would make a separate fetchAsObject method in your array class, or introduce an optional asObject parameter (boolean, default false) to your existing fetch method.

Answer (score 0):

If in first case you are returning raw PHP Array it is **not possible**. 
You can do that way:

```
public static function fetch($key, $as_object = false) 
{
    //in $data you have your array
    return ($as_object) ? (object)$data : $data; 
}

myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords');  //return array
myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords', true);  //return object
```

Or just simply like that:

```
$dataAsArray = myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords');
$dataAsObject = (object)myArray::fetch('site.meta.keywords');
```

Comment: If it were possible, wouldn't it be nice? :)

Comment: Like I said, when you want to return *raw* PHP array it isn't possible. But with little code (extending ArrayObject) and adding method `as_object` it could be done. But why, when you can cast array to object -> look edited version of my answer.

Comment: alright, multi-dimensional arrays? The casting array to object will not good practice in multi-dimensional array. In this case, inner arrays remain still as array.

Comment: Yes - my solution from answer will work for one dimensional arrays. If you want multiple, first part of my previous comment will be an answer.